# Getting an error on only one page of a ASP.NET C# Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, webforms, visual-studio-2017

When I try to run the below page, I get a message in the Developer tools that says

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

When I try to click on one of the links in the navigation area, nothing happens on the page, but there is an error of

Uncaught TypeError: theForm.submit is not a function
    at __doPostBack (wumimluc.aspx:27)
    at WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions (WebResource.axd?d=pynGkmcFUV13He1Qd6_TZIxr8M8jcBphXQ6Het1Rj0xvw-e3AKSeTjIdVEAZ4OM_eNqIH9jZmmPdBkh9S…:42)
    at :1:1

I do not have this issue anywhere else in the project, and I don't understand what is going on. Below is the code for the page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="88px" ImageUrl="~/images/taslogo.png" Width="370px" ImageAlign="Middle" style="display: block; margin: auto; width: 370px" /></div>
<hr />
    <div  style="text-align: center">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Home" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/WarehouseMain.aspx">Home</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton ID="WhExFrMgmt" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wefm.aspx">Export Freight</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton ID="whImFrMgmt" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wifm.aspx">Import Freight</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton ID="WhUldMgmt" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wum.aspx">ULD Management</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        <br />
        | Inbound ULD Management&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wumom.aspx">Outbound ULD Management</asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wumst.aspx">ULD Stock Take</asp:LinkButton> |
        <br />
        | Inbound ULD Transfer (LUC)&nbsp;
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/wumimucm.aspx">Inbound ULD Manifest (UCM)</asp:LinkButton> |
    </div>    
<hr />

    <asp:Table runat="server">
        <asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>ULD Type</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>ULD #</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>ULD Suffix</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Transferred From</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            <asp:TableHeaderCell>Condition</asp:TableHeaderCell>
        </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType1" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum1" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff1" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom1" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition1">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType2" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum2" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff2" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom2" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition2">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType3" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum3" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff3" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom3" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition3">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType4" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum4" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff4" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom4" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition4">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType5" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum5" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff5" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom5" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition5">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType6" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum6" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff6" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom6" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition6">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType7" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum7" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff7" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom7" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition7">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType8" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum8" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff8" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom8" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition8">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldType9" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum9" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff9" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom9" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition9">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="UldType10" type="text" size="6" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldNum10" type="text" size="10" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell ><input id="UldSuff10" type="text" size="4" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell><input id="TransFrom10" type="text" /></asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Condition10">
                       <asp:ListItem>SER</asp:ListItem> 
                       <asp:ListItem>DAM</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell>
        </asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    <br />
    <button runat="server" text="Save" id="save">Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<button runat="server" text="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have not been able to find anything helpful on Google or here.

Comment: The Synchronous XMLHttpRequest error is benign and probably doesn't have anything to do with your problem.  Can you post the code-behind for one of your ASPX pages?

Comment: Sounds like there might be a JavaScript error when you load the page, can you confirm?

Comment: @KevinRaffay The code-behind doesn't have anything at this point, except for an empty Page_Load method. I'm just getting the navigation and design in place right now.

Comment: @Seano666 I'm not using any JavaScript, but there are no errors in the console when I load the page.

Answer (score 1):

After some messing around with it, it appears that the button object does not like having an id of submit. Changed the Submit button id to sub and the error went away.